# Disable time slots based on current hour in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've a simple thing to accomplish. I want to disable timeslots based on current hour. i.e If it 1PM i want to disable previous time slots.
Here is my html:

```
    <div class="  col-sm-4  col-md-4  col-lg-4">
    <md-select placeholder="Select Time" name="type" class="wd-100pc[(ngModel)]="Input.timeslot">
      <md-option>Select Slot</md-option>
      <md-option value="7AM-8AM">7AM-8AM</md-option>
      <md-option value="8AM-9AM">8AM-9AM</md-option>
      <md-option value="9AM-10AM">9AM-10AM</md-option>
      <md-option value="10AM-11AM">10AM-11AM</md-option>
      <md-option value="11AM-12PM">11AM-12PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="12PM-1PM">12PM-1PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="1PM-2PM">1PM-2PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="2PM-3PM">2PM-3PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="3PM-4PM">3PM-4PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="4PM-5PM">4PM-5PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="5PM-6PM">5PM-6PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="6PM-7PM">6PM-7PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="7PM-8PM">7PM-8PM</md-option>
      <md-option value="8PM-9PM">8PM-9PM</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
```

How can i accomlish this using typescript. Im doing this on angular 2. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by simply `date` and `getHours` function :

**Component Side :**

```
hours = new Date().getHours(); // will return 24 hours
```

**Template Side :**

```
<md-select placeholder="Select Time" name="type" class="wd-100pc[(ngModel)]="Input.timeslot">
    <md-option>Select Slot</md-option>
    <md-option value="7AM-8AM" [disabled]='7 <= hours'>7AM-8AM</md-option>
    <md-option value="8AM-9AM" [disabled]='8 <= hours'>8AM-9AM</md-option>
    ....
</md-select>
```